# TO_CHAR equivalent function for IBM db2 v 9.1

Tags: sql

well what i need to do is the following:

```
------------------------------------  : display using IBM db2 
 TO_CHAR(24, '00009')                 :   00024   (version 9.7)
```

however the above SQL does not work when using IBM db2 version 9.1
can anyone indicate to me the correct function to implement the above TO_CHAR() function in IBM db2 version 9.1
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try the `VARCHAR_FORMAT`

([TO_CHAR](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0007110.htm) is a synonym for VARCHAR_FORMAT.)

More to read: [VARCHAR_FORMAT scalar function](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0007110.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the reply 
i also tried  VARCHAR_FORMAT but this did not work. The fact is that i am not working with timestamp. What i want to do is suppose i have a 4 digit and a 3 digit number:
  4251
   573
i want to display them in form of 7 digit number like below:
  0004251
  0000573
respectively.
the TO_CHAR scalar function does the job when using IBM db2 version 9.7 but does not work for IBM db2 9.1.
I need a solution which works well in both cases.Does anyone have any idea how to do so?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can try LPAD function

eg:
select lpad('4251',7,'0') from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1

0004251

select lpad('573',7,'0') from SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1

0000573

Hope it helps :-)